# ObjectListView drag and drop to RichTextBox

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, richtextbox, objectlistview

So I have an objectlistview (actually a treelistview). I want to be able to drag an item from this onto a richtextbox, and have it insert a property of the dragged item (in this case `Default_Heirarchy_ID`)

The TreeListView's objectmodel is a `List<T>` of a class called `SpecItem`.

This is what I have so far:

```
    public frmAutospecEditor(SpecItem siThis_, List<SpecItem> lstStock_)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtFormula.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(txtFormula_DragEnter);
        txtFormula.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(txtFormula_DragDrop);
        ...
    }

    void txtFormula_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void tlvSpecItem_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        int intID = ((SpecItem)tlvSpecItem.GetItem(tlvSpecItem.SelectedIndex).RowObject).Default_Heirarchy_ID ??0;
        DoDragDrop(intID, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
    private void txtFormula_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {

        object objID = e.Data.GetData(typeof(String)); 
        //this is where it goes wrong - no matter what I try to do with this, it 
        //always returns either null, or the text displayed for that item in the TreeListView,               
        //NOT the ID as I want it to.
        string strID = (string)objID;
        txtFormula.Text = strID;
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The Drag is the control you want to take data from (your OLV).
The Drop is the destination control (your textbox). So:

Set the `IsSimpleDragSource` property of your OLV to true.

In the textbox set `AllowDrop` property to true. Then handle the `DragEnter` event of your textbox and use the `DragEventArgs` param.

Handle the ModelDropped event:

```
private void yourOlv_ModelDropped(object sender, ModelDropEventArgs e) 
{ 
   // If they didn't drop on anything, then don't do anything 
   if (e.TargetModel == null) return; 

   // Use the dropped data: 
   // ((SpecItem)e.TargetModel) 
   // foreach (SpecItem si in e.SourceModels) ...

   // e.RefreshObjects(); 
}
```

Read more: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/dragdrop.html#ixzz1lEt7LoGr